# How to disable SSL when using TypeORM to connect to MySQL database

Tags: node.js, ssl, mysql2, typeorm

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database via a Node API using TypeORM with SSL disabled. I am using MySQL2 as the client to connect with the database.

I have made many changes in the ormconfig playing around with different connection options but none of them have been successful.

ormconfig.ts

```
// import {
//   SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2,
//   SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3,
//   SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1,
//   SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1,
//   SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_2
// } from "constants";
import { ConnectionOptions } from "typeorm";

export function getConfig() {
  const isTest = process.env.NODE_ENV === "test";
  // const secureOptionsBitMask: number =
  //   SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 |
  //   SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 |
  //   SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1 |
  //   SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1 |
  //   SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_2;
  return {
    autoSchemaSync: false,
    database: DB_NAME,
    entities: DB_ENTITIES,
    host: DB_HOST,
    logging: "all",
    migrations: "./test/*-migration.ts",
    migrationsRun: isTest,
    password: DB_PASS,
    port: DB_PORT,
    ssl: {},
    synchronize: false,
    type: DB_TYPE,
    username: DB_USER
  } as ConnectionOptions;
}
```

server.js

```
import { Connection, createConnection } from 'typeorm';
import { getConfig } from '../../ormconfig';

let dbConnection: Connection;
...
dbConnection = await createConnection(getConfig());
...
```